# How to get the current controller instance in laravel EventHandler？

Tags: php, laravel

I have set some params In my BaseController:

```
class BaseController{
    public $user;
    public $param;
    ...
    __construct(){
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        $this->param = Input::all();
        ...
    }    
}
```

Now I can use $this->user to get the user info in every controller.

But now, I want to get the user info in UserHandler@update for log. How to get the instance of current controller? like:

```
class UserHandler{
    public function onUpdate()
    {
           $instance = SomeClass::getCurrent();
           $user = $instance->user;
    }
}
```

I don't want to use Auth::user() method. Because that's a complex process in my case.

Comment: And how do you call or instantiate your UserHandler? Is that via Events?

Comment: Whats the problem with using Auth::user()? Thats all you're doing in the controller, so whats the issue with doing that in the event handler? Hacking something together to get an instance of your controller is going to be a huge hacky mess.

Comment: if event is tied to user action please do use Auth facade... Laravel is clever. Install debugbar and see yourself how many db queries you have (and how many duplicates).

Comment: I have used third party authentication package to get the user by token,that's a huge hacky mess too.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, everything sits in a container called the Application

```
$controller = app(\Illuminate\Routing\Route::class)->controller;
```

And also, there is a nicer way

```
$controller = request()->route()->controller;
```

> Tested on Laravel 7.29.3